# Recover a removed .sh file that I just executed

Tags: shell-script

I am making a .sh script. Along with the process I accidentally deleted the script itself with `rm`. I just executed this script many times through the development, can I recover the .sh file from execution history or something similar?

The process is not running anymore, but I have executed it many times. I have looked at .bash_history, but it contains only the execution of the script itself not what's inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chances of getting your script back are very low (sorry). What is more important is in the future not to use the `rm` command if you are not sure. I use `trash-put` instead (which you can download if it isn't already on your system. the program which provides it is `trash-cli`) This uses the same trash system which graphical file managers use. Another option is to always use `rm -i` to prompt you before removing the file.

Here is a related question about retrieving files deleted through `rm` which has a few potential solutions: [How to recover a removed file under Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux)

Comment: I was following a tutorial about removing all hidden files from a folder. A command contains many * that I got confused and in the end I just paste the thing and hit enter.. not to mention that I am about to do a git commit too. Anyway I have already doubled my work. Thanks.